# Как сделать чтобы страница не дергалась? Когда убираем скроллбар?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Проблема такая, что когда открывается модальное окно, то используется правило overflow: hidden; чтобы отключить прокрутку. Это вызывает скрытие скроллбара, на виндовых устройствах скроллбар фиксированный когда исчезает дергает контент.
Помогите советом как решить данный баг.

```
.popup{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 100;
}

.js-blockScroll{
    overflow-y: hidden;
    /*padding-right: 20px;*/
    /*width: auto;*/
}
```

Comment: Это не баг, а нормальное поведение браузеров. К какому блоку применяется `overflow: hidden;` ? Приведите разметку и стили.

Comment: узнать ширину скроллбара и при добавлении `overflow: hidden` этому же элементу (которому добавляется `overflow: hidden`) добавлять `padding-right: x`, где х - ширина скроллбара

Comment: @UModeL привязал

Comment: @meine пробовал, не работает

Comment: как вы пробовали?

Comment: @meine в коде приведен пример кода, где закомментированны стили, там была попытка с падингом

Comment: Модальное окно должно перекрывать все элементы, а следовательно, быть _fixed_ или _absolute_ и быть прямым потомком либо `<body>` либо другого главного контейнера. При таких условиях, ни на какой скролл ничто влиять не будет. Пересмотрите разметку.

Comment: @UModeL перес в боди, не работает

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Есть два решения этой проблемы:

**1. Динамический сдвиг на ширину полосы прокрутки.**

Для этого нужно динамически определять ширину прокрутки. У элемента `html` изначально должно быть `overflow-y: scroll`. Модальное окно при этом будет открываться со свойством `position: fixed`. Перед открытием модального окна, элементу `html` задается `overflow: hidden`, а элементу `body` задается `margin-right: (ширина полосы прокрутки)px` (при этом у обоих элементов не должны быть заданы ширины `width`). Далее запускается слушатель события `window` `resize`, и при масштабировании окна, динамически корректируется `margin-right: (ширина полосы прокрутки)px` у элемента `body`.

При скрытии модального окна отключается слушатель `window` `resize`, убираются `margin` у `body`, а элементу `html` возвращается свойство `overflow-y: scroll`.

Ширину вертикальной и горизональной полосы прокрутки обычно определяют с помощью такой функции (попробуйте запустить ее при разных масштабах страницы):

```js
    var getScrollBarSize = (function() {
      var el = window.document.createElement('textarea'), style = {
        'visibility': 'hidden', 'position': 'absolute', 'zIndex': '-2147483647',
        'top': '-1000px', 'left': '-1000px', 'width': '1000px', 'height': '1000px',
        'overflow': 'scroll', 'margin': '0', 'border': '0', 'padding': '0'
      }, support = el.clientWidth !== undefined && el.offsetWidth !== undefined;

      for (var key in style) {
        if (style.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          el.style[key] = style[key];
        }
      }

      return function() {
        var size = null;
        if (support && window.document.body) {
          window.document.body.appendChild(el);
          size = [el.offsetWidth - el.clientWidth, el.offsetHeight - el.clientHeight];
          window.document.body.removeChild(el);
        }
        return size;
      };
    })();
    
    console.log(getScrollBarSize());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

У этого способа есть несколько особенностей. Полоса прокрутки всегда отбражается в настольных браузерах, независимо от содержания страницы. Правильная реализация должна учитывать направление контента `dir="ltr"` или `dir="rtl"`. Сдвигать придется не только `body`, но и все элементы, имеющие `position: fixed` позиционированные от той стороны с которой находится прокрутка. Последние версии браузера IE имеют баг с масштабированием полос прокруток (полосы прокрутки окна браузера и элементов имеют разную ширину, что не дает правильно определить ширину прокрутки).

**2. Верстка слоями.**

Создается глобальный элемент `div id="wrapper"`, и глобальный скролл переносится в него, а у элементов `html`, `body` - отключается:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

html > body > #wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Все модальные окна, при этом, также размещаются внутри `body`, на одном уровне с элементом `#wrapper`. Тогда у вас вообще не будет проблем с полосами прокруток, так как у каждого слоя они будут свои. Но у этого способа есть несколько особенностей... В мобильных браузерах перестает скрываться панель инструментов браузера. Вместо `position: fixed` вы везде должны как-то обходится с помощью `position: absolute`, что иногда совсем не "гибко". Вам нужно также задать @media print стили для корректной печати такого сайта.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло:)